# JQuery remove link target attribute code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We have a WP site that uses a 3D Cart Plugin - when you click on "Add to Cart" it opens a new window. This is because *'target='_NEW''* is built into the plugin link code. See the following page and click on any Product Description or Add to Cart button.

http://tipsybir.nextmp.net/freestyle-hummingbird-feeders-375ml/

To override this, I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("a[target='_new']").removeAttr("target");
});

</script>
```

which I got from a previous question here. We have another WP site using the same plugin, and the above code works perfect, but it is not working on this site. It is the same exact code, placed in the header, but a new window is still opened.

Can anyone help on this? We do not want a new window to open.

Comment: you are not included jQuery library in your page, better to check your console. You can see `$ is not a function`

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not a developer clearly!

Comment: Is there different casing in the code compared to the html. _NEW : _new?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably **not** using jQuery [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), so use `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a[target='_new']").removeAttr("target");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed that I did not have the JQuery Library loaded.